# Problema Javascript Collapse

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tenho uma lista com collapse para reproduzir conteúdos diferentes no mesmo local, eu só preciso que quando eu entre na página o primeiro item da lista fique selecionado, eu tenho um script que faz a função de fechar uma div caso o usuário clique em outra, aqui estão os códigos, eles ficam dentro do arquivo content.js, aproveitando a pergunta, no inspecionar, quando estou na página home
o console acusa um erro.

```html
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
    at hide_all (content.js:6)
    at window.onload (content.js:21)
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
function id( el ){
        return document.getElementById( el );
}
function hide_all(){
        var divs = id('content1').getElementsByTagName('div');
        for( var i=0; i<divs.length; i++ )
        {
                divs[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
}
/* http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/event.shtml */
function disablelink( e ){
        var evt = window.event || e
        if (evt.preventDefault) //supports preventDefault?
                evt.preventDefault()
        else //IE browser
                return false
}
window.onload = function(){
        hide_all();
        var as = id('content1').getElementsByTagName('a');
        for( var i=0; i<as.length; i++ )
        {
                as[i].onclick = function( e ){
                        hide_all();
                        var id_el = this.href.split('#')
                       
                        id( id_el[1] ).style.display = 'block';                
                        return disablelink( e );
                }
        }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content1" class="container-content container-height">
<ul id="test-content" class="no-padding">
<li class="list-left list1 selected" ><a href="#item1">Reposição LCD</a></li>        
<div id="item1" class="item1">
 <p class="titulo">Reposição LDC</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
<img scr="#"/>
</div>
 
<li class="list-left list2"><a href="#item2">Reposição TOUCH</a></li> 
<div id="item2" class="item2">
 <p class="titulo">Reposição TOUCH</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariaore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
 
<li class="list-left list3"><a href="#item3">Reconexão Display / Frontal</a></li>
<div id="item3" class="item3">
 <p class="titulo">Reposição Display</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in , sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
 
<li class="list-left list4"><a href="#item4">Montagem MO</a></li> 
<div id="item4" class="item4">
 <p class="titulo">Montagem MO</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
 
<li class="list-left list5"><a href="#item5">Reposição Display Frontal</a></li>
<div id="item5" class="item5">
 <p class="titulo">Reposição Display</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
 
<li class="list-left list6"><a href="#item6">Aplicação Peliculas</a></li>
<div id="item6" class="item6">
 <p class="titulo">Aplicação de Peliculas</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
 
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara porque cv não faz esse sistema tipo por Tabs, aqui tem um exemplo básico com Bootstrap para ilustrar a ideia https://codepen.io/wizly/pen/BlKxo

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é adicionar um parâmetro booleano na sua função hide_all(pularPrimeiro) e pular o hide do primeiro elemento caso ela for true.

Já o erro do getElementsByTagName não ocorreu aqui no snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
function id( el ){
        return document.getElementById( el );
}
function hide_all(pularPrimeiro){
        var divs = id('content1').getElementsByTagName('div');
        var iAux =(pularPrimeiro) ? iAux=1 : iAux=0;
        
        for( var i=0+iAux; i<divs.length; i++ )
        {
                divs[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
}
/* http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/event.shtml */
function disablelink( e ){
        var evt = window.event || e
        if (evt.preventDefault) //supports preventDefault?
                evt.preventDefault()
        else //IE browser
                return false
}
window.onload = function(){
        hide_all(true);
        var as = id('content1').getElementsByTagName('a');
        for( var i=0; i<as.length; i++ )
        {
                as[i].onclick = function( e ){
                        hide_all();
                        var id_el = this.href.split('#')
                       
                        id( id_el[1] ).style.display = 'block';                
                        return disablelink( e );
                }
        }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content1" class="container-content container-height">
<ul id="test-content" class="no-padding">
<li class="list-left list1 selected" ><a href="#item1">Reposição LCD</a></li>        
<div id="item1" class="item1">
 <p class="titulo">Reposição LDC</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
<img scr="#"/>
</div>
 
<li class="list-left list2"><a href="#item2">Reposição TOUCH</a></li> 
<div id="item2" class="item2">
 <p class="titulo">Reposição TOUCH</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariaore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
 
<li class="list-left list3"><a href="#item3">Reconexão Display / Frontal</a></li>
<div id="item3" class="item3">
 <p class="titulo">Reposição Display</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in , sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
 
<li class="list-left list4"><a href="#item4">Montagem MO</a></li> 
<div id="item4" class="item4">
 <p class="titulo">Montagem MO</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
 
<li class="list-left list5"><a href="#item5">Reposição Display Frontal</a></li>
<div id="item5" class="item5">
 <p class="titulo">Reposição Display</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
 
<li class="list-left list6"><a href="#item6">Aplicação Peliculas</a></li>
<div id="item6" class="item6">
 <p class="titulo">Aplicação de Peliculas</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
 
</ul>
</div>
```